# Saving two colour indexed (1bpp) PNG with Image Sharp

Tags: imagesharp

I'm using Image Sharp in an ASP.Net Core project and now need to prepare PNG images for a device that can only handle 2 colour indexed PNG images.

If I use the following code, then the images are saved as palleted 2 colour images, but the result is corrupt, looks to me that there is no pixel packing happening.

```
private void ConvertToMonoPng(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
    Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load(fileName);

    var enc = new PngEncoder();
    enc.CompressionLevel = PngCompressionLevel.Level9;
    enc.ColorType = PngColorType.Palette;
    enc.BitDepth = PngBitDepth.Bit1;

    image.Save(stream, enc);
    image.Dispose();
}
```

The results are:

*Source Image*

[image: Source image]

*Output Image*

[image: Output image]

I know that the ImageSharp library doesn't currently support sub-byte packed pixels in memory, but since there does seem to be some support in the PNGEncoder, I'm hoping that saving monochrome PNG's is supported and I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd guess not, given the 'todo' here: https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/v1.0.0-beta5/src/ImageSharp/Formats/Png/PngEncoderCore.cs#L271 It might be simple enough to add some extra cases there if you know what you're doing? But if that's not it you might have to just step through ImageSharp writing the PNG until you spot something it's doing wrong and fix that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place. Yes, it looks like there is no support for 1bpp greyscale, but it does seem to handle 2 colour palleted PNG's which is what I was trying (and works but creates corrupt images) - either would suit my requirements. I'm fairly sure now that this sits somewhere between a bug and unsupported function, so will have a go at adding support inside ImageSharp.

Comment: After seeing this question I've started a work-in-progress PR for ImageSharp that will add the encoding functionality you require. Once it is complete and merged I'll add an answer below with the build version number that contains the missing features.

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/712

Comment: @James thank you that's an amazing response! Looking forward to testing the update.

Comment: You gave me the prod I needed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of build [1.0.0-dev001921](https://www.myget.org/feed/sixlabors/package/nuget/SixLabors.ImageSharp/1.0.0-dev001921) this is now possible. I've added support for 1,2, and 4 bit encoding to accompany the existing 8 and 16 bit encoding.

You can install the package via the nightly MyGet feed using the following command.

```
PM> Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -Version 1.0.0-dev001921 -Source 
https://www.myget.org/F/sixlabors/api/v3/index.json
```

Here's the output.

**1 bit palette**

[image: 1 bit palette]

**2 bit palette**

[image: 2 bit palette]

**4 bit palette**

[image: 4 bit palette]

**1 bit grayscale**

[image: 1 bit grayscale]

**2 bit grayscale**

[image: 2 bit grayscale]

**4 bit grayscale**

[image: 4 bit grayscale]

Comment: I have updated through myGet and can confirm that it's working very nicely. Thank you James, I really appreciate the update!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: so, a lot of thermal printers accept only 1 bit BMP files. Any chance to support exporting 1 bit BMP?